# Angularjs filter page loads first time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

There was a final problem when the project finished. How to avoid filtering when page loads first time.

For example : Opening page with TV checked ? (ng-checked="true") Other amenities is false. If the visitor lifts the tv checkin, the filter is renewed.

My project : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toplumdusmani/zcgs7yf6/21/)

```js
angular.module('hotelApp', [])
    .controller('ContentControler', function ($scope, $timeout) {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, -98.0000),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }
    $scope.location_name = "";
    $scope.names = [{
        prop_Name: 'Location 1',
        lat: 43.7000,
        long: -79.4000,
        amenities: '3'
    }, {
        prop_Name: 'Location 2',
        lat: 40.6700,
        long: -73.9400,
        amenities: '2'
    }, {
        prop_Name: 'Location 3',
        lat: 41.8819,
        long: -87.6278,
        amenities: '4'
    }, {
        prop_Name: 'Location 4',
        lat: 34.0500,
        long: -118.2500,
        amenities: '1, 2'
    }, {
        prop_Name: 'Location 5',
        lat: 36.0800,
        long: -115.1522,
        amenities: '2, 3'
    }];
    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    $scope.markers = [];

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var createMarker = function (info) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
            title: info.prop_Name
        });
        marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent"><ul>' + '<li>' + info.prop_Desc + '</li>' + '<li>' + info.prop_Addr + '</li>' + '<li>' + info.prop_Price + '</li>' + '<li>' + info.prop_Dist + '</li>' + '</ul></div>';

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content);
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        });

        $scope.markers.push(marker);

    }

    for (i = 0; i < $scope.names.length; i++) {
        createMarker($scope.names[i]);
    }

    $scope.openInfoWindow = function (e, selectedMarker) {
        e.preventDefault();
        google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
    }

//PROBLEM FILTER HERE   
$scope.am_en = function()
{
  x = $(".hosting_amenities input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
  $scope.ot_Filter = function (location) {
   var shouldBeShown = true;
   for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (location.amenities.indexOf(x[i]) === -1) {
          shouldBeShown = false;
            break;
        }
    }
   return shouldBeShown;
  };
}



    $scope.$watch('nas',
    function (newValue, oldValue) {
        for (jdx in $scope.markers) {
            $scope.markers[jdx].setMap(null);
        }
        $scope.markers = [];
        for (idx in $scope.nas) {
            createMarker($scope.nas[idx]);
        }
    }, true);
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 220px;
  width: 400px;
}

.infoWindowContent {
  font-size: 14px !important;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
#total_items
{
 margin:0px auto;
 padding:0px;
 text-align:center;
 color:#0B173B;
 margin-top:50px;
 border:2px dashed #013ADF;
 font-size:20px;
 width:200px;
 height:50px;
 line-height:50px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
#amount
{
 color:#DF7401;
 font-size:18px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
#slider-range
{
 margin:0px auto;
 padding:0px;
 text-align:center;
 width:500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false&extension=.js"></script>
<div ng-app="hotelApp" ng-controller="ContentControler">
<div id="map"></div>
    <div id="class" ng-repeat="marker in markers"></div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in nas = (names | filter:ot_Filter)">{{ x.prop_Name }}</li>
    </ul>
    
    
<div class="hosting_amenities">
<h3>Filter:</h3>
<input type="checkbox" name="more_filter[]" value="1" ng-checked="false">WIFI
 <input type="checkbox" name="more_filter[]" value="2" ng-checked="true">TV
<input type="checkbox" name="more_filter[]" value="3" ng-checked="false">Cable TV
<input type="checkbox" name="more_filter[]" value="4" ng-checked="false">Klima 
<button ng-click="am_en();">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you only change the filter once you press the button Submit. However, I recommend you to remove that and place the function `ot_Filter` outside of the function triggered when you click it. This will make the initial filtering when you load the page possible.

As the next step, I would use `ng-model` instead of `ng-checked`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="more_filter[]" value="1" ng-model="ot_Checkboxes['wifi']">WIFI
<input type="checkbox" name="more_filter[]" value="2" ng-model="ot_Checkboxes['tv']">TV
<input type="checkbox" name="more_filter[]" value="3" ng-model="ot_Checkboxes['cableTV']">Cable TV
<input type="checkbox" name="more_filter[]" value="4" ng-model="ot_Checkboxes['klima']">Klima
```

The properties would be initialized in your javascript:

```
$scope.ot_Checkboxes = {
    'wifi': false,
    'tv': true,
    'cableTV': false,
    'klima': false
};
```

With these changes your code will update your locations automatically. This is a good practice and you can keep a good control of your elements. You will find more information about how to set this properly in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27411893/6255258)

In order for you to see how it looks like, I modified your fiddle [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/zcgs7yf6/23/)

Comment: thank you so much. It worked great. I just started learning angularjs. I am trying to learn over the internet no school here. I finished my project with your help. thank you..